# Windows 8 not showing 5GHz networks

Tags: windows-8

Windows 8 currently doesn't pick up my 5GHz network or any 5GHz network for that matter. I had Windows 7 before which picked up all 5GHz networks with no problems. I am able to connect and see all the 2.4GHz networks in my vicinity without an issue.

I have a [Cisco WMP600N](http://home.cisco.com/en-eu/products/adapters/WMP600N) which is compatible with Windows 8 and have tried [suggestions](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-networking/cant-find-5ghz-on-linksys-wmp600n/97b2ad73-d22d-420b-9973-f283c19360c8) by others but nothing has worked.

How can I connect to my 5GHz network again in Windows 8?

Comment: Could be a problem with the Cisco driver. You can try re-installing the driver in compatibility mode.

Comment: It is prob. because there is no official support for Windows 8 by Cisco.  Best bet would be to contact Cisco to look to see if they are planning to support that card with Windows 8.

Comment: The post I linked above suggested to reinstall driver. It didn't work

Comment: Was Windows 7 able to pick up this specific 5GHz network?  Do you have any other devices that can see this network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem connecting to the 5Ghz band with a Linksys WMP600N PCI card to a Linksys E4200 running DD-WRT build 19342 under Windows 8 Professional (RTM). The problem is definitely the driver that is included in Windows 8 as the same hardware had no problems under Windows 7.
I was able to solve it by manually installing the Windows 7 (!) driver from the Linksys (Cisco) support website:
Windows 7 Driver
04/30/2012
Ver.3.2.7
To do this:

1. Unpack the downloaded driver to your computer
2. In desktop mode, right click the wifi icon in the right lower corner and select "Open network and sharing center"
3. Click "Change adapter settings"
4. Right click you wifi adapter and select "Properties"
5. Click "Configure"
6. Go to the "driver"-tab
7. Click "Update driver"
8. Click "Browse my computer for driver software"
9. Click "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
10. Click "Have disk"
11. Browse to the location where you unpacked the downloaded Linksys driver
12. Select your network adapter and click "Next" to install the driver
13. Close all windows
    Check if you see your 5Ghz band

Taken from [Technet Answers](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/e179301b-0325-4372-8697-6b4f5edb0b72/)